# 日本語に違和感: 「識者」バッジ

Tags: バグ, 完了

特に Stackoverflow という文脈で「識者」と言った場合、普通考えるのは、何らかのプログラミングのトピックに関する有識者、つまり expert ということじゃないでしょうか。ツアーを読んでもらえるのは「informed」バッジですが、この訳語としては「識者」は適切ではないと思います。

適切な訳語が無いので日本語でも「インフォームド・コンセント」などと言われていますが、これは本来非 expert である患者が、権威である医療者の言いなりにならないで、治療の内容を理解した上で同意するという概念で、ツアーを読んでサイトの趣旨を理解した上で利用するという informed につながると思います。なので、代案訳は「理解者」。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

提案通りに「理解者」に変換しました。

次回のビルドで適用になります。